# AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone know if the reasoning behind the use of dollar methods and variables in angularJS is to instruct angularJS to avoid checking those values when a digestion is going on? So, if angular comes across `$scope.$value` and `$scope.value`, then it will avoid checking the former since it's prefixed with a dollar character in its variable name?

Comment: See also this blog post, on the [difference of "$scope" and "scope" in angularjs](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/aw9kWmdnik/angularjs-scope-vs-scope)...

Comment: Angular is probably trying to take $ away from jQuery.

Comment: That link redirects to a page that doesn't explain much about $scope.

Comment: The docs for directive -- controller has `$scope`, but directive has `scope`. WTF?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There are a few times Angular ignores variables prefixed with the dollar sign:

1. In [Schumli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables#comment19433906_12648794) below, where json filters will not output them
2. When using the `{{ }}` directive, angular will not show *nested* `$`
   variables. For example this only displays the `visible` property.

   ```
   <div ng-init="n = { visible: 'foo', $ignore: 'bar' };">{{ n }}</div>
   ```
3. Additionally when adding an explicit watcher on a scope object, changes to properties with a leading dollar sign of this object will not trigger the watcher. See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Tfb/13/).
4. `angular.equals()` [ignores keys prefixed with `$`](http://jsfiddle.net/R9Tfb/14/).

Comment: Yeah looks like you're right. Even with click events and so on it still changes. Thank you.

Comment: There are certain parts of Angular that do ignore prefixed properties, for example the 'json' filter will not output a variable starting with '$'.

Answer (score 121):

It is just a naming convention from the below snippet
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

> '$' Prefix Naming Convention
>   You can create your own services, and in
>   fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention,
>   angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other angular
>   APIs have a '$' prefix in front of the name. Don't use a '$' prefix
>   when naming your services and models, in order to avoid any possible
>   naming collisions.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace

> Angular Namespace
>   To prevent accidental name collision, Angular
>   prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $.
>   Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally
>   collide with Angular code.

Comment: Why does the directive doc [1] have `$scope` in controller, but `scope` in directive?  --- [1] https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @LeeGee It's just convention. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19289054/114558

Answer (score 31):

The `$` prefix denotes a variable, parameter, property, or method that belongs to the core of Angular.

Properties on objects that originate inside the framework, but are not actually part of the API, may begin with `$` – or even `$$` – to denote a **private** method or property. This is the same way the `_` prefix is often used in other libraries.

It doesn't have any effect on the way code is interpreted by the runtime, although the framework itself may give it special meaning. Basically, it is a naming convention that says "You shouldn't mess with this".

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The *runtime* doesn't care what variables are named. You could call it `$$__$_$` – it's just an identifier with no special meaning for the interpreter.

Comment: I added a few words to highlight the distinction between runtime and framework; be so kind as to change your vote.

Answer (score 7):

Not completely sure, but I believe AngularJS internals rely on manipulating these $-prefixed variables during the digest. Checking these variables would mean that the digest would never stabilize, since they may constantly change during each cycle of the digest.

Don't quote me on it though. :)

Comment: Downvoted because of: "Don't quote me on it". Sorry, but an answer that admits uncertainty isn't a very useful one :(

Comment: Edited to remove uncertainty.

Comment: Downvote converted to an up-. Assuming you're right, this is now a useful answer!

Comment: @DavidRivers, if the answer initially came as hesitant, rewording it will not make it more useful. In fact, the answer can be _wrong_ and the lack of hesitation would _assert the potential wrongness_. Instead, for this answer to be considered useful, it should be backed-up with some proof by citing _trusted_ sources, or provide a fiddle to reproduce the expressed points.

Comment: @AlexFord I don't want anyone to assert confidence while being unsure. I just figure that an answer isn't helpful if the answerer doesn't even take the time to make sure he's right. Your cynicism really wasn't necessary.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov: I absolutely agree with you. I assumed (possibly wrongly) that the answerer double-checked that he was right and didn't simply reword the answer to remove uncertainty. I suppose I should have wanted sources or fiddles.

Comment: @AlexFord: Hey, man. Thanks for the apology! I'm sorry I wasn't clear and started all this miscommunication anyway. Your point is valid and I agree with you. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't being misrepresented, but I wasn't clear with my own wording. Anyway, no hard feelings and I really respect that you were able to see my point of view. Cheers, man!

Comment: @DavidRivers It got rolled back. I can see why.

Answer (score 5):

Dollar (**$**) signs also prevent elements from being iterated (or interpreted) in certain directives.
So for example properties that start with **$** are not used in `ng-repeat` because of [an if clause in the for loop](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L420):

```
if(collection.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.charAt(0) != '$')
```

Someone made an issue about the topic [here on angulars github page](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6266)

---

In the method `shallowCopy` properties that start with **$$** are skipped because of an [if clause while iterating the properies](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L900):

```
if (!(key.charAt(0) === '$' && key.charAt(1) === '$')) {
```

Answer (score 4):

I always figured `$` looks like an "S" for service.

Comment: that's the correct answer.  It's logical and simple.  These are in fact services so it's better to remember $ 'S' is for service.  nice simple explanation.

Comment: $scope is a service?

Answer (score 2):

@MarcoS provided the link to https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/scope-vs-scope which explains a difference between $scope and scope.  I found this useful, adding to the information in other answers.

In an angular directive there is a link and controller.  The link is a standard function with a fixed set of parameters: scope, element, attributes object.

The controller's arguments are managed by the Angular injector and are not order dependent. The injector resolves which objects to pass in by looking for the parameters starting with $.

The author of https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/scope-vs-scope does a better job of explaining it.

Answer (score -1):

There's a huge difference, not in variables, but in the parameters that a controller receives. A scope parameter is completely different from a $scope one.

For more information, check out this useful post: http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/aw9kWmdnik/angularjs-scope-vs-scope