# Object not accessible in AngularJS view. Strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't access an object property in AngularJS view. Simple but very crazy issue.

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGYyj/2/)

Code below. `operators.date` and `operators.boolean` are not available in AngularJS view. How do I access the property?

```js
$scope.operators = {
    date: {'$lt':'before', '$gt':'after', '$eq':'equals'},
    boolean: {'$eq': 'is'},
    all : ['before', 'after', 'contains', 'does not contain', 'equals' ]
};
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables.  This is an issue with the property names starting with `$`. When using the `{{ }}` directive, angular will not show nested `$` variables. And in general the team warns against using variables beginning with `$`.

Comment: thanks, it's working. If you want add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, this is an issue with the property names starting with $. When using the `{{ }}` directive, angular will not show nested $ variables. And in general the team warns against using variables beginning with `$`. See [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)