# Meaning of the double dollar ($$) syntax in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following expression in **AngularJS**:

```
attrs.$observer('attribute1', function(value){
  isolatedScope.isolated1 = value;
});
attrs.$$observers['attribute1'].$$scope = parentScope;
```

I understand that the above expression somehow means that **the scope for the observer for `attribute1` should point to the parent scope**.

But can someone please tell me what this **double dollar syntax** means in here and more generally in AngularJS?

***Note***: the following code is taken from a book (Mastering web application development with AngularJs, Packt) and is meant to explain the behavior of a isolated scope in the context of a directive:

```
scope: {
 isolated1: '@attribute1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double dollar ($$) sign is intended for AngularJS' internal tracking stuff to keep things in order, you should not bother to use / modify them and you are highly discouraged to do so.

Comment: Yep, those are like private-private properties, keep out :-)

Comment: Fine. But I just meant to understand them :-) not use them in production code. It is not because they seem to be undocumented and "private-private" that it should be forbidden to mention them or explain their purpose and how they are used internally... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Secret revealed in [What is the $$ (double dollar sign) used for in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular). :)

Just in case you arrive to this conversation, as it is the first result in Google.