# Access to value of promise object angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

```
var requestOne = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: $rootScope.apisrvr + 'user/user_signin',
                    data: { username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password },
                });
```

This is my code, when I write: `console.log(requestOne);` I get:
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajKUf.png)

I just want get `$$state / value / data / salt`. But when I try `console.log(requestOne.$$state.value.data.salt);` I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`. How I can get `salt` from here?

Comment: Upvoted the correct answer below, but in general remember that [any Angular property that begins with `$$` is _private_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular) and should be accessed through non-private methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requestOne` is the promise variable itself, to actually get the result, you need to add a `.then` call to the end of the promise like so:

```
var requestOne = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: $rootScope.apisrvr + 'user/user_signin',
                    data: { username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password },
                }).then(function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                });
```