# what is the use of "$$" in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

can any one please help me to understand what is the use of $$. I came across a code snippet like "$scope.$$watchers" and could not understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically since $$ means private variable, if someone outside of the angularJS file is using it, either he really know what he was doing or he shouldn't have done that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion that  $$  prefix is used for internal (non public) API and is by definition not to be used by consumers of angular.js.

Basically the behavior of  $$  properties e.g.  $location.$$compose  might change or even cease to exist without any breaking change notification

---

It is just a naming convention from the below snippet
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

> '$' Prefix Naming Convention
>   You can create your own services, and in
>   fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention,
>   angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other angular
>   APIs have a '$' prefix in front of the name. Don't use a '$' prefix
>   when naming your services and models, in order to avoid any possible
>   naming collisions.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace

> Angular Namespace
>   To prevent accidental name collision, Angular
>   prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $.
>   Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally
>   collide with Angular code.

More details : [What is the $$ (double dollar sign) used for in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular)