# What is the reason of using $$ while defining object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I find this code in a AngularJS base front-end application:

```
var xyz= {
           FileUrl: "some url value",
           CreatedDate: new Date(),
           $$file: "some value in base64 format for file"
         };
```

I search through net but I, do not find any good answer why $$ use for defining object property of JavaScript. I mean what is benefit of using $$ in object property.

Comment: You should go through [What is the $$ (double dollar sign) used for in angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular)

Comment: Is same rules apply for function that define like:  this.$onChanges = function () {}. $ sign carry no special meaning?

Answer (score 0):

$$ means that it's a private variable.

Edit:
This is just a naming convention used by Angular to signal you that you shouldn't use this property directly, as they could remove it or change the usage in a future release.
Since it's just a naming convention, nothing in Javascript prevents you to use it though, however you shouldn't really do it for the reason mentioned above.

Comment: Does this work of pure javascript.

Comment: No in pure JS $$ means nothing, the question was about AngularJS and in AngularJS $$ means it's a private variable.