# angularjs - understanding $ mark and services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've been doing the tutorial from angular page but I don't understand why services (like $scope, $http) have names which begin from $ ?? what this $ mark means in context of angular? If I write own services should I give them the names which begin from $ too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a convention [info](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

> '$' Prefix Naming Convention
>   You can create your own services, and in fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention, angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other angular APIs have a '$' prefix in front of the name. Don't use a '$' prefix when naming your services and models, in order to avoid any possible naming collisions.

You can also check this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables).

Answer (score 1):

I think the $ sign is a kind of namespacing so that the names of the angular services don't crash with that of other javascript libs or objects.

So you don't need a $ sign for you own services.