# Are Angular core services preceded by '$'?

Tags: angularjs

I'm loving Angular so far and am trying to tie up some loose ends.

So in the following:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.factory('Auth', function Auth($location, $rootScope, Session, User, $cookieStore){
```

Is it correct to assume Session and User are user defined services, and $location, $rootScope and $cookieStore are core services? Is there any case when user defined services might have a preceding '$', or core services do not?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12648543/473467 – see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13497741/473467)

Comment: @awendt thank you, I didn't see that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13497741/2460773).

from angular's docs:

> '$' Prefix Naming Convention
>   You can create your own services, and in fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention, angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other angular APIs have a '$' prefix in front of the name. Don't use a '$' prefix when naming your services and models, in order to avoid any possible naming collisions.