# What is .$on() in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I got  this code `$rootScope.$on('abc',function(event, next, current){   });` in a tutorial.

My question is what is `.$on()`? If it is a function, then why is it preceded by `$`?

Comment: You can tell it is a function because you're calling it with `()`. The `$` is basically meaningless. The Angular framework just has `$` on their properties, just like `$rootScope` does. It reminds you that it's from Angular, basically. Meaningless. `$.on` is just a function that attaches an event listener. Read the docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)

Comment: [Check API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on), it has all answers you need here

Comment: In my experience with AngularJS, which is admittedly limited, `$on` works nearly as same as the jQuery `on` function. The $ just signifies it's a reserved public Angular identifier.

Comment: @aarosil Thank you, the first thing people should do is find the official documentation, and I am impressed no answers gave a link.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`$on` is related to `$broadcast` and `$emit` - which is a way to trigger code from other places.

The first thing about `$on` you should know is that it's a method of `$scope`

The second thing you should know is $ prefix refers to an Angular Method, $$ prefixes refers to angular methods that you should avoid using.

Now lets get into detail about what `$on` is.

Below is an example template and its controllers, we'll explore how `$broadcast/$on` can help us achieve what we want.

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name"/> 
    <button ng-click="register()">Register </button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    Registered Name: <input ng-model="name"/> 
</div>
```

The controllers are

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.register = function(){

    }
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope){

});
```

My question to you is how do you pass the name to the second controller when a user clicks register?  You may come up with multiple solutions but the one we're going to use is using $broadcast and $on.

**$broadcast vs $emit**

Which should we use?  $broadcast will channel down to all the children dom elements and $emit will channel the opposite direction to all the ancestor dom elements.

The best way to avoid deciding between $emit or $broadcast is to channel from the $rootScope and use $broadcast to all its children.  Which makes our case much easier since our dom elements are siblings.

**Adding $rootScope and lets $broadcast**

```
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){
    $scope.register = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('BOOM!', $scope.name)
    }
});
```

Note we added $rootScope and now we're using $broadcast(broadcastName, arguments).  For broadcastName, we want to give it a unique name so we can catch that name in our secondCtrl.  I've chosen BOOM! just for fun.  The second arguments 'arguments' allows us to pass values to the listeners.

**Receiving our broadcast**

In our second controller, we need to set up code to listen to our broadcast

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    console.log(args);
    $scope.name = args; //now we've registered!
  })
});
```

It's really that simple. [Live Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YWKE0d6KzyHvIxK8os3V?p=preview)

**Other ways to achieve similar results**

Try to avoid using this suite of methods as it is neither efficient nor easy to maintain but it's a simple way to fix issues you might have.

You can usually do the same thing by using a service or by simplifying your controllers.  We won't discuss this in detail but I thought I'd just mention it for completeness.

Lastly, keep in mind a really useful broadcast to listen to is '$destroy' again you can see the $ means it's a method or object created by the vendor codes.  Anyways $destroy is broadcasted when a controller gets destroyed, you may want to listen to this to know when your controller is removed.

Comment: nice ans! But I couldn't follow why should we use `function(events, args)` and why doesn't `function(args)` work as we are'nt using the event args in the function ??

Comment: @NishanthMatha This how Angular has defined it.  Event has its uses, just happened to not be useful in the example I've provided.  From the event parameter we can determine which scope we were in or preventProgation, etc..

Comment: Thank you. So the `$on` by default has access to `event` parameter?? If so does all the other angular inbuilt function have access to `event` parameter??

Comment: Yes the listener function in $on has `event` as its first parameter.  Not all angular inbuilt functions as this, since $on is listening to an event that is being fired off, it has this.

Comment: Sorry may be a novice question, but if your two controllers are assigned to two different views in app,js under .config , in this case SecondCtrl will not get any data, as the controller will be re-instantiated, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a very good one. I'd like only to add a short remark: this $on kind of listener has a very important property: can be canceled (stoped).
I'll explain what do I mean:

The html:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input ng-model="name"/> 
    <button ng-click="register()">Register </button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    Registered Name: <input ng-model="name"/> 
</div>
<hr/><br/>
<button ng-click="disableEvents()">Disable events</button>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.cancelOn = $scope.$on('BOOM!', function(events, args){
    console.log(args);
    $scope.name = args; //now we've registered!
  });

  // this will cancel the event listening....
  $scope.disableEvents = function(){
    console.log('Canceling the event listener: ', $scope.cancelOn());
  }
});
```

If you press the "Register" button, you can see it communicate with the second controller.  Now press the "Disable events" button. This will cancel the listener, the $on(...). Now, if you press again the "Register", you'll notice that the listener is no longer listen for this kind of event.