# What is the $ in node Modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I can't find anything on it when I search the web.  What's the '$' used for in node modules?

for example in this code he's using them all over:

[Dashboard Controller](https://github.com/cengage/qametrix/blob/master/public/modules/dashboard/dashboardController.js)

Comment: 1° your link was not good. 2° that's just angular

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)

Answer (score 1):

@We Do TDD: The dashboard controller example you cited above is an angular.js based module. Angular do use $ character for few internal variables/objects. It has nothing to do with node module. The $ character doesn't have any significance in node.js world. you can use it  as you like.

Answer (score 0):

the `$` in a javascript variable is just like any other char.  You will see use of `_` (underscore) a lot too.

Some people use it as an indicator of something, some people like it because they are PHP fanboys.

**Edited to add** Now that you have updated the question to be about angular, please see : [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)