# Ng-Model="something.$" what does this mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm new to Angular and I was reading over the filter documentation and I saw this code.

```
    <label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
    <label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
    <label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>


    <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

I'm unclear on what the `ng-model="search.$"` means. The two way binding with `ng-model` is clear, but what about the `"search.$"`? What is that doing and how does it work with the filter.

I tried searching for this and couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible someone created a variable called $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specific to the *filter* logic. `$` is used as a property matcher to match against the values of all the properties on the object in the list. So here in your filter the bound expression is the object `search` and specifying the matcher string as `$` property (which is the ng-model for the search input) on `search` will enable the filter to compare values on all the properties of `friendObj` for a match.

[See doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter#Arguments)

> Note that a named property will match properties on the same level only, while the special $ property will match properties on the same level or deeper. E.g. an array item like {name: {first: 'John', last: 'Doe'}} will not be matched by {name: 'John'}, but will be matched by {$: 'John'}.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: It is recommended not to use '$' since variables like $index are reserved for angular itself. But that's it -  there is nothing special with symbol '$', you can write <input ng-model="$"> and $scope.$ = 'Input name'.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Perhaps not for this purpose. This is just a part of an input object which is used to compare against. Also the documented feature itself says this is the way you can do a universal comparison. The issue of prefixing properties with `$` does have an impact in places like an [ng-repeat on object keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337469/ng-repeat-looping-partially-over-an-object/33337678#33337678) where one of the keys starts with `$` and places like when angular.equals is used.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the documentation right above the example you copied:

> A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties.

So by binding a textbox to `search.$`, the example is enabling search on all of the available properties.