# what is the use of a dollar ($) sign in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables) but either i don't understand the answers or maybe it's not exactly the same question.

In the angularjs guide on [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) there are multiple examples of views where a $ sign is used before a ctrl variable like in the following:

```
Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}<br>
```

In the heroDetails controller, there is no $ sign before the ctrl variable. If I remove the $ signs in the heroDetails.html it does't work anymore.

Can anybody explain it to me, please ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `controller` property is the reference to controller instance, that will be used by the component. The name of the controller in the view is declared by using the `controllerAs` property. If you don't state `controllerAs`, the default is `$ctrl`. So the $ sign is just a part of the name.

```
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  controller: HeroDetailController, // the controller class
  controllerAs: 'whatever', // the controller alias in the view - default $ctrl
  bindings: {
    hero: '<',
    onDelete: '&',
    onUpdate: '&'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you make a `Component`, its controller is identified in the view as `$ctrl`.

It's referenced in the [Component documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

```
                   -------------------------------------------------
                  |        Directive        |       Component       |
    --------------|-------------------------|-----------------------| 
   | controllerAs | Yes (default: false)    |  Yes (default: $ctrl) |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The symbol `$` is the prefix used by Angular for its own variables/properties.