# $data in AngularJS ngTable doesn´t working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am playing with ngTable and I am not achieve suceess with $data.

The $data shows nothing, when I trying show my data with angular.

If I change the code to use a scope variable( as xdata) and to use this variable into ngRepeat all works well, as:

```
...
$http.get(testUrl)
    .then(function(res) {

      $scope.xdata=pac;
      return pac;
     }, function(reason) {
        console.log(error)
   }
 );
```

but, I´d prefer use $data.

The 'pac' array is only a sample of my data returning from mongo server and I am using it to test.

With $data my sample test doesn´t works and, using scope variable, the sample test and using real data  to test all work.

What am I doing wrong?

markup:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" export-csv="csv" class="table table-stripped table-bordered" show-filter="true">
                    <tr ng-repeat="paciente in  $data track by row.id">
                        <td title="'Nome'" filter="{ nome: 'text'}" sortable="'nome'">
                            {{paciente.nome}}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

controller:

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
            }, {
                getData: function (params) {
                  var pac=[{id:21,nome:'JACENI FERRARI ALENCAR'},
                      {id:23,nome:'PEDRO HENRIQUES MARTINS SOUZA'}];

                  var testUrl = '/findallclientes';
                  $http.get(testUrl)
                         .then(function(res) {
                          params.total(2);
                          return pac;
                        }, function(reason) {
                            console.log(error)
                        }
                    );
                },
            });
```

Comment: Use "`paciente in  xdata`" instead of "`paciente in  $data`", the scope variable is $scope.xdata

Comment: Otherwise, change `$scope.xdata=pac;` to `$scope.$data=pac;`

Comment: OK, but my question is why $data is not working. In demo site from ngTable it is used and It works. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

$ as is a prefix used by AngularJS for public ($) and private ($$) properties.. As has already been commented you want to use the controller referenence or $scope.$data... Though you should read the answers here [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)