# $watch not firing on variables with a dollar ($)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

i have a watch for an object. when a property of the object changed, the watch fires, unless the property name starts with a dollar ($).

consider this code:

```
$scope.data = {};

$scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('fired', newValue);
    }, true);
```

and the html:

```
<div>
this will fire the event
<input type="text" ng-model="data.x" />
</div>
<div>
this won't
<input type="text" ng-model="data.$" />
</div>
```

you can see it for yourself in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gtrwzsn1/179/

this is very important for me, since I must use a property name with $ for filter purposes.

Comment: This seems to answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs has "$watchCollection" function as a means to observe changes in a collection (i.e. either an Array or an Object).

```
$scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('fired', newValue);
});
```

Please try above snippet as you want to watch an object. Hope this helps.

Comment: brilliant, thanks!