# Bind min- and maxDate to variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

After a long day of trying to figure out AngularJS directives I finally got my date picker working, the only thing that would make it perfect now is the live change of the min- and maxDate.

> Business case: I want to select a date when I started working on a
>   project. Then I  realize I selected the wrong date and that the
>   project started later. I change the project's startdate and also want
>   to correct the date I started working at it.

In that case with my current code the minDate in the date picker is still set to the old project's start date.

Is there an easy way to do this given my following (working) state?

(I don't know how to actually make this playable in jsfiddle or so, because this is an extract from a much bigger project that I don't know all dependencies of yet and I just started with AngularJS)

In the Main HTML file I call my custom date picker like this:

```
<custom-date-picker
                 input-model="selectedProfile.startDate"
                 min-date="project.startDate"
                 max-date="project.endDate"
>
<custom-date-picker>
```

Here's the directive part in js:

```
.directive('customDatePicker', () => {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl: 'assets/directives/custom-date-picker.html',
                    scope: {
                        inputModel: '=',
                        minDate: '=',
                        maxDate: '=',
                    },
                    controller: $scope => {
                        if ($scope.minDate && $scope.maxDate) {
                            $scope.dateOptions = {
                                maxDate: $scope.maxDate,
                                minDate: $scope.minDate,
                                startingDay: 1
                            };
                        }
                    },
                    link:
                        function (scope) {
                            scope.inputModel ? scope.inputModel = new Date(scope.inputModel) : false;
                        }
                }
            }
```

And lastly the template that's referenced in the url of the directive:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="inputModel"
       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
       uib-datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
/>
```

(Question on the side: it seemed the `$` in `$scope` is necessary - is it really? - why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend told me about the magic AngularJS functionality called `.$watch` :D

Turned out to be very simple with that, I simply added those lines in the controller and it worked:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(scope) { return scope.minDate },
    function(newValue) {
        $scope.minDate ? $scope.dateOptions["minDate"] = new Date(newValue) : false;
    }
);
```

[Reference](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

EDIT for more than one variable which was the case for me I used:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(
    ["minDate", "maxDate"],
    function (newValues) {
        $scope.minDate ? $scope.dateOptions["minDate"] = new Date(newValues[0]) : false;
        $scope.maxDate ? $scope.dateOptions["maxDate"] = new Date(newValues[1]) : false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably achieve what you want using AngualrJs's [$broadcast, $emit, and $on.](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx) When the date is changed, you can $broadcast or $emit the event with the new date, and then use $on to update the date in your input.

I have used [Angular Date Range Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-daterangepicker) to achieve this functionality myself; below is the code for my directive.

```
.directive("fieldDate", ["$parse", function($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(mv) {
                    if (mv == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return DateUtil.format(new Date(mv.year, mv.month - 1, mv.day), "MM/dd/yyyy");
                });
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(vv) {
                    if (StringUtil.isBlank(vv)) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    var date = DateUtil.parse(vv, "mm/dd/yy");
                    return DateUtil.toDateObj(date);
                });


                elem.daterangepicker({
                    "showDropdowns": true,
                    "linkedCalendars": false,
                    singleDatePicker: true,
                    autoUpdateInput: false,
                    "opens": "center",
                    "drops": "up"
                })
                    .on("apply.daterangepicker", function(ev, picker) {
                        $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
                            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign($scope, DateUtil.toDateObj(picker.startDate.toDate()));
                        });
                    });
            }
        };
    }
```

The `.on()` function at the bottom of the directive receives the event named `apply.daterangepicker` from the `daterangepicker` library, and assigns that value to my model.

---

For your side question, the reason the `$` is required in `$scope` is because Angular used that to prevent naming collisions between built-in services and objects and those defined by the developer. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)